# jQuery return position of list element with class on table column click

Tags: jquery, class, list, position

I was wondering how to return the position of a list element with a class of 'currentTab' in the following unordered list:

```
<ul id="coverTabs">
    <li class="currentTab"><a href="#">Individual</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Couple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Single parent family</a></li>
</ul>
```

The class is set in the HTML to start.  The following sets the clicked tab to 'currentTab' and then removes the previous class:

```
$('ul#coverTabs > li').live('click', function() {

    // Clickable tabs
    // Removes default class applied in HTML and onClick adds 'currentTab' class
    $(".currentTab").removeClass("currentTab");
    $(this).addClass("currentTab"); 

});
```

I thought if i added the following to the above it would return the position of the tab that is currently current so to speak:

```
    // Find the active tab
    var tabPosition = $('ul#coverTabs > li.currentTab').index ($('.currentTab'));
    var tabPosition = tabPosition + 1
```

It doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword when referring to the current item ..

```
var tabPosition = $('ul#coverTabs > li').index ($(this));
```

Although the problem in your case was that you were limiting the index inside the currentTab, so you were selecting only one ..

```
var tabPosition = $('ul#coverTabs > li').index ($('.currentTab'));
```

the above should work as well (note that i have removed the `.currentTab` from the first selector)

Comment: Thanks.

Quite an obvious mistake but it's been a long day.  So glad i have found this place.